# Função insere não funciona

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Estou construindo uma lista encadeada pra guarda uma string com a seguinte assinatura no registro:

```
typedef struct Lista *Noticia;

struct Lista {
    int hora; 
    char *Texto; 
    struct Lista *PN; 
};
```

E a seguinte função inserir:

```
void Insere_Noticia (Noticia p, int hora, char txt[]) {
    Noticia q, novo;
    q = p;
    novo = malloc(sizeof(Noticia));
    novo->hora = hora;
    novo->Texto = txt;
    while (q != NULL && q->hora < hora) 
        q = q->PN;
    novo->PN = q->PN;
    q->PN = novo;
}
```

Porém, não está funcionando, e indica o erro na linha `novo->PN = q->PN` tenho em mente que o problema é bem simples, mas nunca trabalhei com listas dessa natureza, com um ponteiro pra char no registro, e acho que esse possa ser o problema, pois sempre declarei a string no registro alocando memória, ex, char Texto[100]. Assim, peço ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `malloc` deve ser feito com o tipo da lista e não o seu ponteiro. Por isso:

```
novo = malloc(sizeof(Noticia));
```

Deve na verdade ser:

```
novo = malloc(sizeof(struct Lista));
```

Porque `Noticia` é na verdade um `struct Lista *`, e apresentando o `sizeof` de cada um conseguimos ver que não corresponde ao que se pretendia:

- `sizeof(struct Lista)` => 12
- `sizeof(Noticia)` => 4, porque é um ponteiro

A função no entanto só irá funcionar se tiver pelo menos um nó inicial, pois ela não contempla o facto da lista ser `NULL`. Caso ela seja `NULL` o código salta por cima do `while`:

```
 void Insere_Noticia (Noticia p, int hora, char txt[]) {
 q = p;
 ...
 while (q != NULL && q->hora < hora) //salta se q nulo
```

E na linha a seguir crasha porque tenta desreferenciar um ponteiro nulo:

```
novo->PN = q->PN;
```

Em que `q` aponta para `NULL` logo não podemos fazer `q->PN`, porque seria tentar aceder ao endereço 0 de memória que não é possível. Aqui tem também outro problema, que é quando a `hora` a inserir é maior que todas as que estão na lista, o que faz com que vá até ao fim e fique no mesmo problema de nulo. Para esse caso sugiro rever a lógica que está a tentar aplicar. Se quiser aplicar uma lógica de se for maior inserir no fim pode fazer o seguinte:

```
//agora enquanto o próximo não for nulo, por isso para 1 antes do fim
while (q->PN != NULL && q->hora < hora){  
    q = q->PN;
}
```

Logo um `main` deste gênero irá funcionar:

```
int main()
{
    Noticia lista = malloc(sizeof(struct Lista)); //primeiro elemento criado manualmente
    lista->hora = 10;
    lista->Texto = "algum texto";

    imprimirLista(lista);
    Insere_Noticia(lista, 5, "outro texto");
    imprimirLista(lista);

    return 0;
}
```

Em que o `imprimirLista` podia ser algo como:

```
void imprimirLista(Noticia n){
    printf("\nInicio");

    while (n != NULL){
        printf("\n->%d %s", n->hora, n->Texto);
        n = n->PN;
    }
}
```

Para funcionar com um inicio de lista a nulo seria necessário modificar a função da lista para receber um ponteiro para ponteiro de lista:

```
void Insere_Noticia (Noticia *p, int hora, char txt[]) {
```

E respetivos ajustes dentro da função.

Ou retornar o novo inicio da lista quando está a inserir o primeiro:

```
Noticia Insere_Noticia (Noticia p, int hora, char txt[]) {
```

Com os seus respetivos ajustes também.